# reordering alphanumeric age group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

assume this is what R gives me.

```
df1 = data.frame(grp = c("<2", "2-5", "21-26","27-32","6-10"), val= rep(0,5))
     grp val
1    <2   0
2   2-5   0
3 21-26   0
4 27-32   0
5  6-10   0
```

but I want R to understand 6 < 21 and to give:

```
df2 = data.frame(grp = as.factor(c("<2", "2-5", "6-10", "21-26", "27-32")), val= rep(0,5))
    grp val
1    <2   0
2   2-5   0
3  6-10   0
4 21-26   0
5 27-32   0
```

I tried mixedsort() from gtools but it returns indices instead of a reordered dataframe.
any tips or idea how to get to this?

edit. Thanks to wonderful @akrun, I realized I must first assign his dplyr suggested answer to another object , say new_df and then pipe new_df to the rest of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done with `parse_number` to reorder the rows with `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(readr::parse_number(grp))
```

-output

```
    grp val
1    <2   0
2   2-5   0
3  6-10   0
4 21-26   0
5 27-32   0
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1[do.call(order, read.csv(text = gsub("<", "-Inf,", 
    chartr("-", ",", df1$grp)), header = FALSE)),]
    grp val
1    <2   0
2   2-5   0
5  6-10   0
3 21-26   0
4 27-32   0
```

Comment: thank you for the dplyr suggestion. so my actual dataframe is very similar to my small example just more rows and columns. both are dataframes, grp colum returns character when taking str(). but I do not know why your cool suggestion works for this one and not for my actual dataframe. any idea what to check for?

Comment: @Mathica Can you show the `unique(df1$grp)` values

Comment: @Mathica Have you assigned the output back to another object or same object i.e. `df2 <- df1 %>%
   arrange(readr::parse_number(grp))`

Comment: it is "<2"  "2-6"  "21-27"  "28-35" "36-50" "7-20" "51+"

Comment: Okay, there is `+` at the end that could be the issue

Comment: @Mathica I tried with `df2 = data.frame(grp = c("<2", "2-5", "21-27","28-35","36-50", "51+", "6-10"), val= rep(0,7));df2 %>% arrange(readr::parse_number(grp)) %>% pull(grp)#
[1] "<2"    "2-5"   "6-10"  "21-27" "28-35" "36-50" "51+"`  it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 4):

you can explicit the desired levels (and force rank order) also with base R:

```
grp <- factor(c("<2", "2-5", "6-10", "21-26", "27-32"),
       levels = c("<2", "2-5", "6-10", "21-26", "27-32"),
       ordered = TRUE
       )
```

note the use of `factor` not `as.factor` in this case

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but if you have a raw set of numbers you're creating a dataframe from, you can also just use `cut()` to create an ordered factor that aggregates your data and then `table()` to count frequencies within each cut range.

```
set.seed(100)
observations <- rnorm(20, 5, 5)
cut(observations, c(0, 2, 9, 10), include.lowest = T) |>
  table() |>
  data.frame()

#     Var1 Freq
# 1  [0,2]    2
# 2  (2,9]   16
# 3 (9,10]    1
```